# Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED ,_REMOVED,_REPLACED

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I searched and tried many solutions but they don't worked perfectly.
I am working on implementing Google map on Android Application using Eclipse. 
The application run but there are errors in LogCat as Shown below:

```
03-08 06:39:54.876: E/Icing(942): Native load error: Native method not found: com.google.android.gms.icing.impl.NativeIndex.nativeGetVersionCode:()I
    03-08 07:51:07.916: E/Icing(942): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED intent due to initialization failure.
    03-08 07:51:13.246: E/Icing(942): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED intent due to initialization failure.
    03-08 07:51:14.466: E/Icing(942): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED intent due to initialization failure.
```

My Manifest file "in application tag ":

```
 <receiver android:name="com.project.sbms.PackageChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

PackageChangeReceiver class:

```
package com.project.sbms;

import android.content.*;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class PackageChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v(TAG, "there is a broadcast");
        }
    }
```

Please HELP!
Thanks in Advance.